# Elaborar uma função que concatene elementos de mesma posição em arrays distintos segundo uma determinada condição

Tags: javascript, aplicação-web

Essa é a minha primeira pergunta aqui no site, então desculpe se meu modo de questionar não seguir o padrão esperado rs.
Estou fazendo um curso de programação **JavaScript** para iniciantes para concorrer a uma bolsa. Em um dos um exercícios propostos (pré-requisito para entrar na disputa) foi elaborado o seguinte desafio:

*Programar uma função filme que recebe três arrays com os nomes de personagens, filmes e ano de estréia no cinema. A função deve receber também um valor de id escolhido pelo usuário com intervalo de 1 até o tamanho máximo dos arrays fornecidos e retornar uma frase com o seguinte modelo: "personagem é um personagem do filme filme que estreou no cinema em lançamento." Se o valor de id for inválido, a função deve retornar a frase "Essa não é uma opção válida."*

*Exemplo:*

*personagens = ["Hermione", "Trinity", "Leia"]*

*filmes = ["Harry Potter", "Matrix", "Star wars"]*

*lancamentos = [2001, 1999, 1977]*

*id = 3*

*Deve retornar a string:*

*Leia é um personagem do filme Star wars que estreou no cinema em 1977*

A função, bem como os arrays, já são dados pelo próprio elaborador e estão inseridos no código da própria máquina, cabendo a mim apenas completá-la a partir da linha que diz "Escreva abaixo o seu código".

Afim de respondê-la escrevi o seguinte código:

```
    function filme(personagens, filmes, lancamentos, id)
{
  // Escreva abaixo o seu código:
  if (id < 1 || id > personagens.length) {
    return ("Essa não é uma opção válida.")
     
  } else { 
    return (personagens[id--] + ' é um personagem do filme ' + filmes[id--] + ' que estreou no cinema em ' + lancamento[id--])

  }
  
}
```

No entanto ao colocá-lo para rodar, o sistema retorna erro da minha resposta. Mais precisamente, eis o que me apresenta:

*Um id inválido deve retorna uma mensagem de erro*

Segundo ele, o meu código não esta retornando a mensagem de erro quando um ID inválido é inserido, tal como exigido pelo enunciado. Mas não vejo como isso é possível uma vez que defini através da condicional **if** as condições em que ele deve fazer o que a questão me pede.

Alguém aí consegue arguir onde está o erro de minha lógica.

De pronto agradeço pela colaboração !

***obs:*** lembrando que se trata de uma questão para iniciantes e portanto não comporta soluções mais elaboradas, basicamente devo resolver a questão usando a condicional if/else, variáveis, arrays e nada mais.

Comment: Você decrementa duas vezes id na linha do return, isso por si só já invalida a postagem como erro de digitação. Outra coisa, exigências específicas de sites de terceiros (muitos são bem duvidosos) acabam atrapalhando a postagem. Aqui é sempre importante um [mcve] do problema, com foco numa dúvida pontual, e não enunciados de exercício.  O [Guia de sobrevivência do Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8045/70) explica isso de maneira bem melhor e pode ajudar em formulações de próximas postagens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A sua solução está parcialmente correta, mas existe diversos erros que devem ser corrigidos.

Partindo do mais básico, em qualquer linguagem de programação, os números começam do 0, então quando eu te peço o primeiro elemento de alguma coisa, tal elemento não se encontra na posição 1, mas na posição 0 e considerando que você começa da posição 0, significa que o seu ultimo elemento na verdade está na posição `length - 1`.

Com isso podemos ajustar o seu `if` para:
`if (id < 0 || id >= personagens.length)`

Como você disse tais arrays serão já preenchidos, e eu presumo que estejam preenchidos corretamente então não iremos verificar nenhum caso em que o array posta estar vazio.

Segundo problema, você precisa conhecer os [operadores](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_operators.asp) lógicos em qualquer linguagem que você for programas, geralmente são iguais em quase todas, ao menos os básicos, no seu caso você está aplicando o operator `--` ao valor do seu `id` cada vez que você lê algum valor com ele, o que significa que se o `id` inicial era 3, por você estar decrementando ele a cada leitura, no final ele vale 1 e se eu bem entendi não é isso que você precisa, mas você precisa ler o elemento que se encontra na mesma posição em 3 arrays diferentes, que seria:

```
(personagens[id] + ' é um personagem do filme ' + filmes[id] + ' que estreou no cinema em ' + lancamento[id])
```

A mensagem que você fez referimento:

> Um id inválido deve retorna uma mensagem de erro

Provavelmente está dizendo que se o `id` é inválido você deve retornar uma mensagem de erro, como um erro. Retornar um texto/string dizendo que o valor é errado não é o mesmo que gerar um erro, erros podem ser tratados dentro a um bloco `try/catch`, e como o nome sugere, o código tenta fazer algo e se um erro for gerado dentro deste algo, ele irá parar no `catch` para talvez mostrar uma mensagem de erro ou coisa do tipo. Então no seu caso ao invés de retornar uma string, você faz o que chamamos de `throw` ou `lançar` uma exceção, em JS você pode fazer no seguinte modo:

```
if (id < 0 || id >= personagens.length)
  throw new Error("Essa não é uma opção válida.");
```

Quando você lança uma exceção o código de execução é bloqueado e a mesma retorna um erro a quem à chamou, e cabe ao chamante lidar ou não com o erro, se não tratado o mesmo pode fazer crashar o seu programar.

O seu código final com um toque de beleza poderia ser algo como:

```js
function filme(personagens, filmes, lancamentos, id){
  if (id < 0 || id >= personagens.length)
    throw new Error("Essa não é uma opção válida.");
  
  // Não é necessário um bloco else aqui, pois uma vez que o seu programa chega a este ponto você pode ter certeza que nenhum erro ocorreu durante a verifica do if
  return `${personagens[id]} é um personagem do filme ${filmes[id]} que estreou no cinema em ${lancamento[id]}`
  
}
```

Dica: Use [interpolação](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals), é mais bonito e mais fácil de ler e você não precisa de preocupar em adicionar vários `+ var +` no seu código.
E se o seu usuário passa um id a função que não começa com 0, o melhor a se fazer é diminuir 1 da variável recebida como input no inicio da função, ou melhor ainda criar uma outra variável que é igual a recebida - 1, desta maneira não tocamos na original e usamos a variável com o valor certo.

Comment: Consegui resolver. A solução acabou sendo um híbrido em sua dica e a do Diogenes Martins.
Sua explanação foi particularmente útil ao esclarecer que estava decrementando o valor da variável todas as vezes que declarava o operador lógico --.
Quando a utilizar o número 1 ao invés do 0 como valor de comparação, era necessário por força da própria questão 
Então, para solucionar a implicância que isso teria nos arrays posteriormente, fui obrigado a decrementar o ID (id--) uma única vez antes de declará-lo na concatenação das strings assim que encerrei a condicional.

Answer (score -1):

Tentei deixar o código mais básico, veja se essa resolveria

```js
function filme(personagens, filmes, lancamentos, id){
      
      if (id >= personagens.length){
        return ("Essa não é uma opção válida.");
        }else{
          id
        return (personagens[id] + " é um personagem do filme " + filmes[id] + " que estreou no cinema em " + lancamentos[id]) 
        }
    }
    
    console.log(filme(["Hermione", "Trinity", "Leia"], ["Harry Potter", "Matrix", "Star wars"], [2001, 1999, 1977], 2))
```

Answer (score -2):

Eu acho que o sistema da Digital House exige um programa exato. sendo assim , apesar de varias soluções, vai continuar gerando esse erro no sistema deles.
Outro detalhe: o código tem que ser básico, usando o conteúdo que foi passado até então no curso, então vai ter erro mesmo se o programa estiver correto como postado pelo Leo Letto.

Eu fiz assim e funcionou exatamente nos teste, mas mesmo assim o sistema do curso não aceita.

https://jsfiddle.net/hLwtr2ef/