# Programar uma função filme - Personagens

Tags: javascript, array, funções

Programar uma função filme que recebe três arrays com os nomes de personagens, filmes e ano de estréia no cinema. A função deve receber também um valor de id escolhido pelo usuário com intervalo de 1 até o tamanho máximo dos arrays fornecidos e retornar uma frase com o seguinte modelo: "personagem é um personagem do filme filme que estreou no cinema em lançamento." Se o valor de id for inválido, a função deve retornar a frase "Essa não é uma opção válida."

Exemplo:

personagens = ["Hermione", "Trinity", "Leia"]
filmes = ["Harry Potter", "Matrix", "Star wars"]
lancamentos = [2001, 1999, 1977]
id = 3

Deve retornar a string:

Leia é um personagem do filme Star wars que estreou no cinema em 1977.

---

meu código:

function filme(personagens, filmes, lancamentos, id){
var personagens = ["Hermione", "Trinity", "Leia"]
var filmes = ["Harry Potter", "Matrix", "Star wars"]
var lancamentos = [2001, 1999, 1977]

```
for(id = 2; id < personagens.length; id++)

if (id >= 3) {
  return ("Essa não é uma opção válida.");
  }else{
    id 
  return (personagens[id] + " é um personagem do filme " + filmes[id] + " que estreou no cinema em " + lancamentos[id]) 
  }
```

}

console.log(filme(["Hermione", "Trinity", "Leia"], ["Harry Potter", "Matrix", "Star wars"], [2001, 1999, 1977], 2))

reotrna erro:

Erros:
Um id inválido dever retorna uma mensagem de erro
Um id inválido dever retorna uma mensagem de erro
Um id inválido dever retorna uma mensagem de erro
Um id inválido dever retorna uma mensagem de erro

Comment: O seu código funciona mas os parametros de personagens, filmes, lancamentos estão a mais. Se os retirar e chamar filme(3) vê que obtem o resultado certo. Ou então não defina esses arrays na função e receba-os por parametro

Comment: Isto responde à sua pergunta? [Elaborar uma função que concatene elementos de mesma posição em arrays distintos segundo uma determinada condição](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/461015/elaborar-uma-fun%c3%a7%c3%a3o-que-concatene-elementos-de-mesma-posi%c3%a7%c3%a3o-em-arrays-distintos)

Comment: tentei como disse, olhei o link indicado, mas continua com o mesmo erro... :(

Answer (score 0):

Eu consegui resolver invertendo a ordem, no if eu coloquei a condição para mostrar a resposta correta, saindo do if fiz a mensagem de erro. Não usei o for.